Extracting attributes from the {Custom Payload} in Dialogflow
When using the data store resource, the chatbot yields the sources as a custom payload that follows the following format:

{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "match_citations",
        "citations": [
          {
            "subtitle": "summary about the file",
            "title": "title_string",
            "actionLink": "link"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Are we able to index these attributes in the "Agent Response -> Agent says" menu, analogously to the index $requests.knowledge.answers ? I'm not using the Python SDK.
I tried referencing $sources but it did not yield anything but the raw string "$sources".
